# match a regular expression to get attribute

Tags: regex

I'm already so desperate with this one. I need to be able to match the following pieces of text but:

1)  despite of any garbage before the text **staveb**
  and
2) I need to match every `<OPTION ....</OPTION>` with occurence of the text **staveb**

**that means, I need to match these pieces of text:**

```
<OPTION value="39">  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Stavebníctvo</OPTION>
 <OPTION value="39">staveb</OPTION>
 <OPTION value="39">staveb</OPTION>
```

**from this text:**

```
<OPTION value="25"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Anglicky</OPTION> <OPTION value="19">Auto, moto</OPTION> **<OPTION value="39">  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Stavebníctvo</OPTION>**   <OPTION value="26">Školstvo</OPTION>
 **<OPTION value="39">staveb</OPTION>**
```

Pleease help!

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
<OPTION\s+value="\d+">[^>]*staveb[^<]*</OPTION>
```

Comment: It should be noted that XML/HTML files should NOT be handles by regular expressions.